# How to derive the following linear recurrence?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

Given a function $f(i)$ defined as $\sum_{r=0}^i P(i, r)$ where $P(i, r)$ is the number of permutation from $i$ items choose $r$, the following recurrence seems to hold: $$f(n) = nf(n-1) + 1$$ A few first values:
\begin{align}
f(0) = &\; P(0, 0) = 1\\
f(1) = &\; P(1, 0) + P(1, 1) = f(0)+1 = 2\\
f(2) = &\; P(2,0) + P(2,1) + P(2,2)= 2f(1)+1 = 5\\
f(3) = &\; P(3,0)+ \dots +P(3,3) = 3f(2)+1 = 16 
\end{align}
I got this recurrence by writing a program and trying to see the pattern, and it seems to be correct. But how to derive it algebraically? Also, is there a nice combinatorial argument for this? Like maybe the equation describes "how to choose $i$ people from a pool of $n$ people while designating a leader" or something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sequence is in the OEIS: https://oeis.org/A000522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that
$$P(n,r) = \frac{n!}{(n−r)!},$$
so that
$$f(n)=\sum_{r=0}^n P ( n , r )=\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{n !}{ ( n − r ) !},$$
and
$$f(n-1)=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} P ( n-1 , r )=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1) !}{ ( n-1 − r ) !}.$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
nf(n-1)+1
=&\;n\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1) !}{ ( n-1 − r ) !}+1\\
=&\;\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{n !}{ ( n − (1+r) ) !} +1\\
=&\;\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{n !}{ ( n − r ) !} +1\\
=&\;\sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{n !}{ ( n − r ) !} \\
=&\;f(n).\\
\end{align}

Comment: Great! I have a question, this might be a little out of topic, but suppose we were not given the recurrence in the first place, do you have any tips how to start deriving it?

Comment: You would need some properties of $P(n,r)$. For instance, I think this property would allow you to go a long way: $P(n,r)=nP(n-1,r-1)$.